# cannot ping website or vmnet8 successfully

Tags: virtual-machine

I run Ubuntu on VMworkstation12, but it can not be connected to the internet.
At first, My friends help me configure the net, it seems to work for a short period, but when I restart the network or Ubuntu, it fails again.
windows 7 (host)
this is the VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:
IP address 192.168.213.1
mask 255.255.255.0

net configuration at VMware:
VMnet8 NAT mode
ip 192.168.213.0
mask 255.255.255.0
getway 192.168.213.2

net configuration of Ubuntu:

## /etc/network/interfaces

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto ens33
iface ens33 inet static
address 192.168.213.3
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.213.2
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

at this situation, I can ping 192.168.213.2 successfully
ping 10.202.214.68(address of host) successfully
but cannot ping 192.168.213.1(VMne8) or any website.
What should i do to make it work?
Really appreciate your help! Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

ok, problem solved almost.
change the dns-nameservers as same as the getway.
the website can be connected to the ubuntu.
but the host still can not ping subnet ip 
the ubuntu can not ping VMnet8